# How do we geometrically multiply and divide circular arcs?

Tags: geometry, circles

Given the ease with which we can geometrically multiply and divide straight-line segments, i would like to ask for guidance on the same problems on the circle, 
not necessarily using "straight edge and compass", but any possible method:

Given two arcs of length x and y on the unit circle, construct arcs of length $x\cdot y, \frac{x}{y}, \,\,\frac{x}{n} \text{  for }n=2,3,4,\ldots$.

The only results i'm aware of are those of the theory of constructible polygons,
with straight edge and compass.

Comment: If you're not restricted to ruler and compass, why not jus multiply $x$ by $y$ to get a number $z$, and then use the arclength integral to determine a point that's distance $z$ from, say, $(1, 0)$? (This assumes that $z \le 2\pi$, or that "wrapping" is allowed). If you do restrict to ruler and compass, then computing $x/3$ is a problem, for this amounts to trisecting the angle.

Comment: @John Hughes: but how do we get the number z = x by y, if x and y are two points given on the circle?

Comment: You didn't ask about dividing or multiplying *points*, you asked about arcs. And to find out the arclengths, you...integrate the arclength integral. It's really, really unclear what you're asking here, or what could possibly be a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @John Hughes: i mean two points x and y, specifying arcs of length x and y, measured from a given initial point on the circle.

Comment: Can you explain what it means to geometrically multiply and divide line segments?

Comment: @Barry Cipra: not sure how to give a totally satisfactory definition. But i can say that "geometrically" means using ruler and compass, or some kinematic curve, as in the ancient geometric tradition, e.g. the quadratrix of Hippias.

Comment: for example using two perpendicular lines and a unit segment, it's easy to geometrically multiply and divide line segments using properties of similar triangles.

Comment: "not sure how to give a totally satisfactory definition." To me, that says it all. You're not willing to take the time to ask a clear and unambiguous question, but you're happy to have us waste our time trying to guess what'll satisfy you. (Hint for clarity: Edwin Moise, **Elementary Geometry from an Advanced Standpoint** actually makes very clear all the constructions for the elementary operations on the reals, done with straight-edge and compass.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a thick disk and a thread. You can roll/unroll and straighten the thread to convert from arc to line segment.

Alternatively, use an Archimedes' spiral. The polar angle and the modulus perform the same transformation.

[image]

Comment: Is there a proof that x*y and x/y can't be done with straight-edge and compass?

Comment: @exp8j: read the comments in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Let's assume a unit circle. Given points $X$ and $Y$ with arclengths $x\in \Bbb R$ and $y\in \Bbb R$ measured counterclockwise from the initial point $P = (1, 0)$, compute, using the axioms of the real numbers, the number $xy$. Then let $U = (\cos(xy), \sin(xy))$; the arclength counterclockwise from $P$ to $U$ is then $xy + 2k \pi$, for some integer $k$. The same approach works for all the other possibilities.

Comment: sorry if i didn't make it clear: x and y are not given numbers, but points on the circle specifying two arcs relative to an origin. The problem is to define the product and the ratio geometrically (to define the sum is easy, we just put the two arcs side by side).

Comment: OK. So let $\theta_x = atan2(v, u)$, where $(u, v)$ are the coordinates of the point $x$, and similarly for $\theta_y$. As for "define geometrically," that's not precise enough to have any useful meaning. After all, we've defined all the operations on the reals geometrically (as you observed yourself),so now using real numbers is...geometric? **Not** geometric? I dunno. Anyhow, my real point was that until you refine your question to make it well-defined, it's not very interesting. Personally...I'm done.